# gitlab проблема с названием

Tags: wordpress, gitlab, виджет

Проект на gitlab для WordPress - виджет. Всем известно, что виджет можно устанавливать, выбрав в админ панели zip-файлик. Когда я с репозитория скачиваю свой виджет (download->zip), то он имеет название `название-виджета-master`, когда же я клонирую репозиторий с помощью git bash, то он называется `название-виджета`. Из-за этого ошибка в ajax (со ссылками, т. к. папки по разному называются). Как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: Выуверены, что выполняете установку правильно ? 
Напишите пожалуйста ссылку на репозиторий.

Comment: Да любой...что на гитхабе, что на гитхабе. Попробуйте скачать zip и он к названию добавляет ветку.